# Android Studio: add directory as a link into an existing module

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way in Android Studio to bring a external directory into the module structure? Without copying it, but as link. It should also interpret correctly different content types (e.g. java files, manifests, resources).
Something like what is in Eclipse with the File -> Import... -> File System.